# My pc was wiped so my Minecraft APP was deleted how doin get it back with my Mojang account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I wiped my computer then my Minecraft app is gone but I know there is some way I can get the app back on my desktop using my mojang account please answer as soon as possible thank you.

Comment: I don't see how this question is on-topic, as a literally identical problem could happen if program deleted was something other than a video game.

Comment: Also: redownload MC?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with games ("how do I get back deleted files/programs?")

Answer (score 3):

You just need to go [the official donwload page](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/) and download it again. Then you can login with your email or username if you made your account before 2011 (I think)

Comment: and this is not skyrim...